# UnCaughtType error in REACT,js when hooking the eventhandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am adding the dropdown list and trying to add the event handler to each item and display the selected item in the Button.when I try to hook the event onClick on the menu items in REACT.js I get this error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribeToEvents' of undefined. Here is my class below

```js
export default class LocationList extends React.Component {


 constructor(props)
 {
  super(props);
   this.state={selectedIndex:"Location",
                data:{
                   cities:       ["Location","Bangalore","Chennai","Pune"] 

               } 
             };


 }
 
  getInitialState()
 {
 
 }

 

 subscribeToEvents(event)
 {
 
 }

  render()
  {
    var titleVal = this.state.selectedIndex;
    console.log(titleVal);
    
    return(
      <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="locationDropDown"  type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{titleVal}
         <span class="caret"></span></button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           {  this.state.data.cities.map(function(city) {
                if(city !='Location')
                {
                  return <li onClick={this.subscribeToEvents.bind(this)} ><a href="#" >{city}</a></li>
                }
             })
            }
         </ul>   
      </div>);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `this` is undefined inside of the function you're passing to `.map()`.

Solution 1:  Bind the correct context of this.

```
this.state.data.cities.map(function(city) {
    if(city !== 'Location') {
        return <li onClick={this.subscribeToEvents.bind(this)} ><a href="#" >{city}</a></li>
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Solution 2: Use an arrow function, which automatically binds the correct context of `this`.

```
this.state.data.cities.map(city => {
    if(city !== 'Location') {
        return <li onClick={this.subscribeToEvents.bind(this)} ><a href="#" >{city}</a></li>
    }
});
```

Comment: Solution 1 didnt work ,Solution 2 worked. Thanks for the solution.